# Custom UITableViewCell dilemma

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I got a kind of problem. At this point I have made a custom tableviewcell, nothing fancy just two labels with 1px white shadow beneath the text. The problem is that when the user (me) select a cell the blue highlighting looks really awkward because of the shadow. So I need to disable/remove the shadow on highlighting.

I have not found any methods which are being called once the user selects the row, just after the user removes his finger.

So at this point I need to subclass UITableViewCell just to write two lines of code in the setSelected-method that does it. Are there any better ways to do this? And yes, I just add views to the contentView property of the cell.

And what is the layoutSubviews-method for? I don't find it in documentation but obviously it is in the iOS so...When does it get called and in what context?

Because when I subclass a UITableViewCell, what should I do with the sizes of the view-components?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The below method is called just before the user is about to select the row....

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```